# Encrypt the config file using DataProtectionConfigurationProvider -Install schield

Tags: wpf, installation, windows-installer, installshield

I am working on a WPF application. I   have used “install shield limited edition” to create the installer setup. As per requirement I want to encrypt the App.config file (using DataProtectionConfigurationProvider)  during  the installation process.

I checked the installer shield  set up project properties. I found that there is “Custom action” section and some of the actions are not locked.

[image]

I want to execute the following code to encrypt the Appsettings section of Appconfig file.

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
                //Gets the source directory of the installation from the default 
                //context parameters 
                Context.Parameters["assemblypath"]);

            // Get the connectionStrings section. 
            ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("appSettings");

            //Ensures that the section is not already protected 
            if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {
                //Uses the Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) to encrypt the 
                //configuration section using a machine-specific secret key 
                section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(
                    "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
                config.Save();
            }
```

But  I found, we have only the option to choose New Exe,VB Script or Jscript.

[image]

How can I implement the encryption of Config file.

Please   guide me a way.

Thanks

Comment: What's the issue with a new exe to run that code? How are you expecting to run that code except by running an exe?

Comment: Do you mean we need to create and new exe  to execute the above code  and need to specify the exe the custom action section of Install Schield?

Comment: Yes, custom actions are your code in a Dll, EXE etc that you insert in the MSI, and Windows Installer will call them at the place you sequenced them.